# Share a cookie across subdomains in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, cookies, subdomain

I have a web application which is hosted at https://example.com. I would like to share a session cookie between the main domain **https://example.com** and sub-domain **https://www.example.com**. Thus, there should be no need for a user to re-login if they switch from one domain to another. How do I achieve this in springboot 2.2.6?

*This is what I have tried:*
I went to application.properties and set **server.servlet.session.cookie.domain=.example.com**
Now, this does not help. I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid domain [.example.com] was specified for this cookie
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.validateDomain(Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.generateHeader(Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java:145) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.generateCookieString(Response.java:973) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
```

If I set **server.servlet.session.cookie.domain=example.com**, then the cookie is not visible for http://www.example.com and if I set **server.servlet.session.cookie.domain=www.example.com**, then the cookie is not visible for http://example.com

I have read discussions about Rfc6265CookieProcessor and LegacyCookieProcessor, but I don't know the right way to fix this issue.

Springboot 2.2.6 uses tomcat version 9.0.*

So, how do I fix this issue?

**EDIT:**

I was trying the above changes on localhost only and not on production. Instead of accessing http://www.example.com, I was doing https://www.localhost and instead of accessing http://example.com, I was doing http://localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right value is:

**server.servlet.session.cookie.domain=example.com**

What I was trying was that I was making changes on localhost and they were not working for me. I was modifying the values in chrome console manually and expecting to see cookies set on https://localhost with domain localhost to be visible in another tab for domain https://www.localhost and that was not happening.

I read the answer here: [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain) and @Cesc 's comment on that answer which was :

> I am not sure where to put this so I am choosing the comments of the
> accepted answer. It took long time and failed experiments to prove the
> above on my localhost, until it occurred to me that I should call the
> localhost with a dot in the name. Like "localhost.com" or something
> like that. Then all the "set cookies" behaviours started following the
> explanations written here in this answer. Hoping this might help
> somebody.

So, I tried my changes on production directly and they worked fine. I am still not able to get it to work on localhost. The way I access my website on localhost is:

https://localhost and https://www.localhost. Based on @Cesc 's comment, I probably need to access the website on localhost as https://www.localhost.com or https://localhost.com and then it will work. But, I have not tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than testing with 'localhost' on your dev machine, try using your machine's fully-qualified host name. I've had a similar challenge with testing authentication against our single-signon platform.